# What are the risks of investing in an unsponsored American Depositary Receipt (ADR)?

Tags: united-states, adr, pink-sheets

What are the risks of investing in unsponsored ADRs? Is the risk different from that of sponsored ADRs?

I initially believed that volume would be a problem for unsponsored ADRs, but then I noticed that some of the highest volume OTC ADRs are unsponsored. For example, Tencent Holding Ltd. ([TCEHY](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/TCEHY/overview)), Nintendo Co., Ltd. ([NTDOY](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/NTDOY/overview)), LVMH Moët Hennessy Louis Vuitton ([LVMUY](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/LVMUY/overview)). Is there a significant risk that volume will dry up and lock me into my unsponsored ADR investment?